# How to include Django CSRF token in JavaScript API fetch?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, csrf

I created simple API in Django and I need to fetch it with JavaScript, I get following error:
Forbidden (CSRF token missing.): URL(placeholder instead of real url)

```
    fetch(`/Post/${content[i].id}`, {
        method: "POST",
       }).then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
```

How can I include token in API call?

Answer (score 4):

There is an example and solution for your problem in [Django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/#:%7E:text=Setting%20the%20token%20on%20the%20AJAX%20request%C2%B6).

```
const request = new Request(
    /* URL */,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
        mode: 'same-origin' // Do not send CSRF token to another domain.
    }
);
fetch(request).then(function(response) {
    
});
```

I hope it could help you.